# Trouble compiling mysql.h with gcc

Tags: mysql, c, gcc

I am absolutely new to both C and Mysql. I am trying to follow the tutorial at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/c-api-building-clients.html and got stuck trying to compile my simple code.

The program is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main()
{
  if(mysql_library_init(0, NULL, NULL))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize client library\n");
      exit(1);
    }

}
```

which I got from the tutorial.

gcc spits out a message saying:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is how I compiled my code, which I suspect is the problem:

```
gcc -I /usr/include/mysql -c sql.c
gcc -o exe -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You do not specify any input files in your second command line. You should feed the result from first command into second. Or use only one command line for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Compiled and runs normally with

```
gcc -I /usr/include/mysql sql.c -o exe -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient
```